# How can I write a "not" expression with changeset pattern?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was checking a folder/file changed or not in a path which defined as "root/docs/.../.../"
I used "when" expression for that purpose.

```
    when {
        changeset pattern: "**/docs/**", caseSensitive: true
    }
```

But I wonder how can I write an "not" pattern expression for example; can I write an expression `"!(**/docs/**)"` to search path to determine a path is not located in "root/docs/.../.../" ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use "not" to negate it:

```
when {
    not {changeset pattern: "**/docs/**", caseSensitive: true}
}
```